# Python flow of execution

Tags: python

Can someone explain the flow of execution of a python program especially about the main function?  It would be helpful if it is compared and contrasted with execution of C.

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) helps

Answer (score 1):

when you execute "python myprog.py"
the python interpeter will start running the script line by line:

```
import os #import the os module
print "prints somthing"
def f(num): ... # define a function

a = 5 / 2.0 # calculating stuff stuff ... 
if __name__ == '__main__': #__name__ is '__main__' only if this was the file that was started by the interpeter
    f(a) #calling the function f...
```

In C there is special function "main" that will be executed at startup.
this (as explained above is NOT true for python)

Answer (score 1):

Without going in-depth, in c you have a specific "entry" function (main):

```
int main() {
    // stuff
}
```

This function is compiled and the executable will start with it.

In python you usually load a specific module (something like `python mymodule.py`) and verify main-ness by checking `__name__`'s value:

```
if "__main__" == __name__:
    print "this is main"
```

The `__name__` variable is usually the module's name (`"mymodule.py"`), with an exception when it is the main module you've loaded (and then it is set to `"__main__"` automagically).